# Finding no-self-intersecting path in geometric graphs

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, np-complete, geometric-graph

**Is there a polynomial algorithm to determine whether there exists no-self-intersecting path between given vertices $s$ and $t$ in a geometric graph $G$?**

*Geometric graph* is an image of a graph on a plane where vertices are represented as points and edges are drawn as straight line segments (possibly intersecting with each other).
A path is called *no-self-intersecting* if every two edges from the path do not intersect.

For example, there exists no-self-intersecting path between highlighted vertices on the following picture,

[image]

but there is no such path on the second picture.

[image]

Here is a **stronger version** of the problem: given a conventional graph $G$, a list of "crossings", where a "crossing" is a pair of edges, and vertices $s$ and $t$, determine whether there is a path between $s$ and $t$ in which no edges form a "crossing". I have a proof it's **NP-complete**, but I don't know a way to convert an arbitrary "graph with a list of crossings" to corresponding geometric graph, in which edges intersect iff they formed a "crossing" in original graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second problem is a variant of problem called *Path avoiding forbidden pairs (PAFP)* (see *Computers and intractability* by Garey and Johnson, 1979, page 203).

I could not find any mention of the main problem, though, so I prooved it is NP-complete. I uploaded the paper to [my Github](https://github.com/harius/harius.github.io/blob/master/data/planarpath_ru.pdf) (sorry, only in Russian).

Comment: The dropbox link is not working.

Comment: @Idonknow Thanks for pointing out! I've updated the link.